# Cannot get user id from Flutter HTTP request

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am trying to connect my flutter app to RESTful API. But I am having some problems. This is just the authentication part.

When I am sending a POST request for Register, I am getting user id as null in the response.
Below is my user model file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

User userFromJson(String str) => User.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String userToJson(User data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class User {
  final String id;
  final String username;
  final String profileImageUrl;
  final String email;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.profileImageUrl,
    this.email,
  });


  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        username: json["username"],
        profileImageUrl: json["image"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "username": username,
        "image": profileImageUrl,
      };
}
```

And this is the response I should be getting from API:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "Davrick"
    },
    "image": null
}
```

Here is my register function:

```
static Future<User> createUser(
      String email, String username, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post("$apiURL/en/users/register/", body: {
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
      "email": email,
    });

    if (response.statusCode != null) {
      final String responseString = response.body;

      return userFromJson(responseString);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

And when I want to get user id, it is showing it as null although in the server I can see that it is adding users with new IDs.

```
_user != null
       ? Text(
       "The user ${_user.username} with id ${_user.id} is created successfully.")
       : Text("No users"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fromJson` constructor needs to first go through the `user` submap. Passing a key to the top level map does not search nested ones.

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
  id: json['user']["id"],
  username: json['user']["username"],
  profileImageUrl: json["image"],
);
```

Trying to get the value of a key that does not exist in a Map will return null, which is why you're seeing null, but not getting any exceptions.

You should likely do the same for `toJson`.

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  "user": {
    'id': id,
    'username': username,
  },
  "image": profileImageUrl,
};
```

---

It turns out the OP posted an incorrect JSON format. With the correct format, the following will work.

```
factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
  return User(
    id: json["user_id"],
    username: json["username"],
    profileImageUrl: json["image"],
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry again. So `toJson` should be something like this:
`"user": {"id": id}`

Comment: @Davrick Yep that's the idea. I edited in an example.

Comment: This gave me an exception `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.`

Comment: @Davrick Can you provide the full error? There should be more than that. Also saying where that error is would be helpful.

Comment: @Davrick That might be where the error is originating. Follow the stacktrace to the source.

Comment: @Davrick Also a note. It seems you user id is a number, but your class represents it as a string.

Comment: `E/flutter ( 7697): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 7697): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 7697): Tried calling: []("id")
E/flutter ( 7697): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
E/flutter ( 7697): #1      new User.fromJson (package:curtain/models/user_model.dart:31:25)
E/flutter ( 7697): #2      userFromJson (package:curtain/models/user_model.dart:4:39)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228648/discussion-between-christopher-moore-and-davrick).